# Why can't connect the AP hotspot?

Tags: wifi

Show the wireless interface:

```
iwconfig
wlx38a28c80c24f  IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment   thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Show hotspot which can be scanned with wireless netcard:

```
wlan="wlx38a28c80c24f"
sudo ifconfig  $wlan  up
iwlist $wlan scan | rg -i  xiaomi -A 5
    ESSID:"Xiaomi_9113"
    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
    Mode:Master
    Extra:tsf=0000022064d81a33
```

I want to connect it:

```
sudo iwconfig $wlan essid "Xiaomi_9113" key xxxxxxxxxx
Error for wireless request "Set ESSID" (8B1A) :
    SET failed on device wlx38a28c80c24f ; Operation not supported.
```

I am sure that the password is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iwconfig ... key ...` configures keys for the obsolete WEP encryption, which is known to be weak. In fact, the entire `iwconfig` command is semi-obsolete, and it is usually recommended to use the newer `iw` command instead.

Modern encryptions (WPA / WPA2 / WPA3) require a `wpa_supplicant` or some other software to manage the WiFi network association.

Your Linux distribution may have some distribution-specific way to configure `wpa_supplicant`, so you should check your distribution's documentation.